# Не могу понять как использовать индексы из Sklearn - KFold

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, big-data, scikit-learn

Не могу получить результат разделения KFold.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
train1, test1, train2, test2 = kf.split(X_data)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Подскажите, кто знает. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входных данных. И какая размерность у `X_data` (`print(X_data.shape)`)?

Comment: print X_data.shape, y_data.shape

Comment: (119, 27) (119L,)

Comment: когда запускаю через цикл на печать, все ок, но как их получить в виде массива

Comment: for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_data):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)

Answer (score 2):

`kf.split(X_data)` возвращает список кортежей (list of tuples) c `n_split` элементами, где каждый элемент списка - кортеж, состоящий из `train` и `test` векторов.

Т.е. для `n_split=2` - `kf.split(X_data)` вернет:

```
[(train0, test0), (train1, test1)]
```

для `n_split=3`:

```
[(train0, test0), (train1, test1), (train2, test2)]
```

где каждый `train*` / `test*` - это вектор (1D Numpy array)

Вот пример:

Setup:

```
In [287]: X = np.arange(24).reshape(-1,3)

In [288]: X
Out[288]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])

In [289]: kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
```

Примитивный (наивный) вариант - работает только для `n_splits=2`:

```
In [302]: (train1, test1), (train2, test2) = kf.split(X)

In [303]: X[train1]
Out[303]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])

In [304]: X[test1]
Out[304]:
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])
```

но лучше делать более гибко:

```
In [290]: train, test = zip(*kf.split(X))

In [291]: train
Out[291]: (array([0, 3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2, 6, 7]))

In [292]: test
Out[292]: (array([1, 2, 6, 7]), array([0, 3, 4, 5]))

In [293]: X[train[0]]
Out[293]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])

In [294]: X[test[0]]
Out[294]:
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])

In [295]: X[train[1]]
Out[295]:
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])

In [296]: X[test[1]]
Out[296]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

А теперь тоже самое для `n_splits=3`:

```
In [297]: kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

In [298]: train, test = zip(*kf.split(X))

In [299]: train
Out[299]: (array([0, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([1, 2, 3, 5, 7]), array([0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]))

In [300]: test
Out[300]: (array([1, 2, 7]), array([0, 4, 6]), array([3, 5]))
```

Comment: Супер, очень понятно. Спасибо. Индексы получил. Разрешите еще вопрос, уточнение:

Comment: При подстановке их в датасет выдает ошибку:

при
X_data[train1]

KeyError: '[  0   1   3   5   6   7   8   9  11  12  13  14  16  18  20  21  22  24\n  25  26  28  29  30  37  41  43  45  47  49  50  51  52  57  60  61  63\n  64  68  70  71  72  73  75  76  79  83  84  86  87  89  92 101 103 106\n 107 108 109 114 115] not in index'

Comment: @АлексейЗахаренков, как вы `train1` получили - это очень похоже на `string representation`...

Comment: (train1, test1), (train2, test2) = kf.split(X_data)

print train1
[  0   1   3   5   6   7   8   9  11  12  13  14  16  18  20  21  22  24
  25  26  28  29  30  37  41  43  45  47  49  50  51  52  57  60  61  63
  64  68  70  71  72  73  75  76  79  83  84  86  87  89  92 101 103 106
 107 108 109 114 115]

X_data[train1]

Comment: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Извиняюсь за стиль сообщений, пока не освоил как код красиво вставлять.

Comment: а какой `train1.shape` ?

Comment: выдает такой: 
(59L,)

Comment: тогда мне понадобиться ваш `data set` чтобы воспроизвести ошибку...

Comment: 'print train1.shape'
(59L,)

Comment: ok, вечером скиную Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Будет достаточно если я скину csv файл?

Comment: @АлексейЗахаренков, да

Comment: Смог решить задачу без этой конструкции, спасибо за помощь.